# R ezperm() error message: replacement has 9 rows, data has 3

Tags: r, permutation, anova

I tried running a within-subjects repeated-measures ANOVA using ezperm(), but I always get the error message

```
Fehler in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "p", value = c(0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 0.4,  : 
  replacement has 9 rows, data has 3

# Fehler = error in German
```

I know there are a lot of questions on StackOverflow concerning this message and I know that normally you get this message when trying to replace certain elements in dfs with too many other elements, but I don't really understand what happened in this case. Can anyone help? This is what I tried to do:

```
rt_perm = ezPerm(
  data = D
  , dv = .(N.back.RT)
  , wid = .(Code)
  , within = .(Situation, Block)
  , perms = 1e1 
)

# df = D, contains the columns Situation, Block, Code & N.back.RT
# predictors: Situation = either online or lab
#             Block = Working memory load (3 diff. levels)
# dependent var. = N.back.RT (Reaction times)
# Code = individual Code for each subject
```

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I have not enough values in some cells & the ezperm() function doesn't like that.